# Zoom in/out image on AbsoluteLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming

I am making an application in which there is one little toy and there are some dresses on the left side(ListView) and you can select dresses. From that listview you have to just choose one dress and the dress will automatically added to the view and now I can drag it easily but I can not zoom in/out it.

Below is my code:

```
       mKittyBGLayer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            for (ImageView img1 : mArrayList) {
                if (kittyStatus == img1.getId()) {
                    mKittyDress = img1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (mKittyDress != null) {
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) event.getX()
                        - mKittyDress.getWidth() / 2, (int) event.getY() - mKittyDress.getHeight() / 2);
                mKittyDress.setLayoutParams(lp);

                // Handle touch events here...
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        // ...
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                mKittyDress.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


      /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `AbsoluteLayout` anymore. It was marked deprecated in API 3, that is more that 10 API iterations ago!

Answer (score 0):

What I've actually done in a situation like this, is use a `WebView` to display the image. That gives the user the scaling / scrolling gestures and inertia that match exactly what they're used to.

Comment: Sticky no yar that is not possible in my application i can add more than one images in only one view and i can drag is also, is all this possible in webview, i think it is not!

Comment: I may be a little confused (and perhaps you could add more detail) on exactly how your application looks. If you have multiple images, perhaps you could still use the WebView -- send it to a page which you have generated, that displays all these images next to each other. You can pretty much display them however you want inside that WebView. Unless, your images aren't actually saved as files at this point?